# R Coding - Export a file

Tags: r

How can I select and export a single column from a data frame as a text file?

The following code exports the complete data frame:

```
lapply(names(dat), function(x){write.table(dat[[x]], 
  file = paste("Output", x, ".txt", row.names=F, col.names=F)))})
```

Comment: `write.table(my_df[[my_column]], file = "my_ffile_name.txt", row.names = F)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = letters[1:10],
                 z = rnorm(10))

df
#     x y           z
# 1   1 a  0.36327112
# 2   2 b  1.56697575
# 3   3 c  0.19387687
# 4   4 d  0.58341133
# 5   5 e -0.32764229
# 6   6 f  0.03953639
# 7   7 g  1.45752921
# 8   8 h -0.91446277
# 9   9 i -1.45858541
# 10 10 j -0.25040698

# If I want to export just column y, you could do...
write.table(df["y"], "output.txt")
# You will likely not want the row names...
write.table(df["y"], "output_without_row_names.txt", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for not being very clear. What I am trying to do is split a data frame based on the values of a particular column, say Col2 and then export only Col1 into different text files.                                        This code will export both Col1 and Col2:                                                  spt1 <- split(df, df$Col2)                                               lapply(names(spt1), function(x){write.table(spt1[[x]], row.names=F, col.names=F,  file = paste("Output", x, ".txt"))})

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
write.table(dat[2],"second_column.dat")
```

to write the second column of the dataframe `dat` to a file.